# Can PHP files with an extension of .php.xx be executed as PHP?

Tags: php, file

Say you have a file `myfile.php` which executes some PHP code. Could this file somehow (any possible way) be executed if it were named `myfile.php.xx`, where `xx` are any characters? What about `myfile.phpxx`? What about other types of executable files in the same situation (.pl, .exe, .dll, etc)?

I'm working on a firewall, using regexes to check file names for these types of files. Is it enough to just check the end of the file for .php, .exe, etc., or should it check what comes after it, too?

Comment: May I ask what kind of firewall that is? Outgoing? Incoming? What's it supposed to protect, a web server?

Comment: It's impossible.  File extension means nothing; you can rename a .exe to anything you want, and you can tell a webserver to interpret any sort of file at all as PHP if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *completely* up to the web server to decide how it wants to handle a given URL. If it wants to treat a URL with a 20-digit number accessed at 2:35 in the afternoon on the third Thursday in the month as a PHP script then that is its prerogative. Attempting to guess what the web server will do strictly by the URL requested is not possible.

Comment: Agreed...the random condition did clarify it for me. I figured this was probably the case, but wanted to see what everyone else had to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The actual PHP interpreter doesn't care the least bit about the filename or extension. You can throw any file at it, if it contains valid PHP code, it'll be executed.

A *web server* defaults to throw `.php` (and possibly `.php4` and `.php5`) files at the PHP interpreter, but can be made to do that with *any* file type with appropriate settings:

```
AddHandler php5-script .foobar
```

It could also default to handling URLs that end in `.php` with a Perl script, a C# program or by erasing its hard disk.

File names mean absolutely **nothing**.

Comment: Reminds me of this guy who configured his Apache to handle .asp files to PHP, and now claims to have an ASP.NET port of WordPress :D  (as a joke of course, but many people get confused about it)